# How can I get a message from another process when I don't have a window handle?

Tags: c, winapi, inter-process-communicat

I have 2 programs, and I need a way for one of them to somehow send a message to the other.  I've looked into the SendMessage function in the Win32 API, and while it works great as long as you have a window handle, my program needs to be able to run while logged off under a service, which means it cannot create a window handle.

Is there any way I can receive messages from another process without having a window handle created?  I've been looking to see if Win32 has some other way that I can hook into the messaging so that I don't depend on having a window handle, but there has to be some way to communicate between processes at a basic level, doesn't there?

I have looked into using Pipe's to do this, but have run into huge permissions issues with that on top of that being much higher level than I'm really looking for.  All I need to be able to do is send a simple custom int message so my process knows it's time to shut down.

Comment: I'm in danger of posting a stupid reply but, have you considered using shared memory for IPC? Seems like a good fit for your application (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also mailslots might be a good fit (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Hope this helps! Let me know if there's something about your application that makes all of these approaches irrelevant.

Comment: I'd go with @Ivan on this one. This could be something as simple as setting a registry value, or a value in a file, and having the service watch or poll for it though. Naff but quick and simple.

Comment: A named pipe is the way to go.  I you get permission problems with them now, that won't get better with any other mechanism.

Comment: Other answers and comments have explained better ways to do this, but to clarify, services CAN create windows, they just can't interact with the desktop or any other sessions.

Comment: @HansPassant SendMessage doesn't give us any permissions issues at all in the exact same situations that pipe's were, so I know that there are ways that do not have as many restrictions.  My best guess for why pipe's were causing those issues is because they can send much more complicated messages

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I've considered the file as a third party route, I just really don't want to have to do that, but thank you for mentioning that possibility.

Comment: @Cdaragorn `SendMessage()` DOES have permission issues when UIPI is enabled.

Comment: @HansPassant "*A named pipe is the way to go. I you get permission problems with them now, that won't get better with any other mechanism*" - one mechanism that is not subject to permission issues is sockets, except maybe for firewall issues, but shouldn't be an issue for connections on the local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's really as simple as signalling the other program to shut down, then you can [create a named event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Both processes create the event with the same name.  One watches it and the other can signal it.  The one watching can do that with a modified message pump that uses [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of PeekMessage.

There's a slight denial-of-service risk here, as a malicious process could create an event with the same name and cause your other application to exit.

If you need more sophisticated communication, you'll need a pipe, mailslot, shared memory, file watches, registry watches, or use another synchronizable kernel event (Mutex, Semaphore, etc.).

Comment: Message pump?  Just need a three-line thread - create named event, wait on it with WaitForSingleObject, call ExitProcess(0).

Comment: @Martin James: I would assume the point is to shut down the process in an orderly fashion, in which case you've probably got to get the notification to the UI thread.  If you just wanted to kill the process, you may as well terminate the process from the other program.  Also, the question implied that he/she would normally do it with a Window message, so I assumed the intent was to receive the notification in the message pump.

Comment: I misread.  I thought the service was sending the signal to the interactive process.

Comment: @MartinJames You're mostly correct, except for the ExitProcess call :).  The point of this is to avoid having to kill the process, and rather allow it to exit cleanly.  That can easily be done with a bool that I can flip from the thread, though, so this solution is looking really promising.

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you so much for pointing me to these functions!  The only difference I made was to use WaitForSingleObject instead, but that's just because it fit what I was needing better.

Answer (score 1):

If your IPC doesn't require any parameters, your service could implement a custom control code that its `Handler/Ex()` looks for, and then other apps can use [`ControlService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-controlservice) to send that control code to the service.

Though, shutting down a service programmably can be done using `ControlService(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)` instead. The service should shut itself down when its `Handler/Ex()` receives a `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` request.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
// msg.c:

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain (_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow) {
    MSG msg;
    DWORD curThreadId;

    curThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

    // Send messages to self:
    PostThreadMessage(curThreadId, WM_USER, 1, 2);
    PostThreadMessage(curThreadId, WM_USER+1, 3, 4);
    PostThreadMessage(curThreadId, WM_USER+2, 5, 6);
    PostThreadMessage(curThreadId, WM_USER+3, 7, 8);
    PostThreadMessage(curThreadId, WM_QUIT, 9, 10);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        printf("message: %d; wParam: %d; lParam: %d\n", msg.message, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Make:

```
> g++ -m64 -mwindows -c -o msg.o msg.c
> g++ -s -o msg.exe msg.o
> msg.exe
message: 1024; wParam: 1; lParam: 2
message: 1025; wParam: 3; lParam: 4
message: 1026; wParam: 5; lParam: 6
message: 1027; wParam: 7; lParam: 8

> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
9
```